# How to Send a word file from one user to another

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, download, controller, paperclip

I want to be able to send a file to another user.  I have attached the file and sent to another users database table.  Now how can I take that file and show a download for the user who is receiving the file. Pulling out the file so that the opposite user can download and view it. I read about the `send_file` but not quite sure how to use it safely!! thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

What I normally do is store the files on the file system of the server instead of actually storing the file themselves in the database.  Everywhere I read it seemed like this was the better thing to do.

You can store the name or location to the particular file you want them to download, then just request that information and download it using the usual `<a href=".." download></a>`.

You can also limit access to certain file locations should security be an issue.

Comment: Where could I start to figure that out?? And this would keep all of the files that have been uploaded?? Im using aws and postgres!!. Im assuming I wouldnt be able to do this on a local server like sqllight? i also use ngrok as a test provider.

Comment: @MichaelLombardo look into s3, it's a part of AWS and is pretty easy to use through gems like carrierwave or paperclip

Comment: Ya I want to use aws!! Im gonna check it out now!! thanks!!